# No puedo completar la instalación de OpenJDK en VS Code

Tags: java, vscode

Soy muy novato, así que seguramente sea una tontería. El caso es que he instalado el OpenJDK 16 que proporciona VS Code desde Java Runtime, pero al dirigirme hacia los settings (JSON), no me aparece la fracción de código para introducir la ruta del Open JDK.

Me aparece esto:

```
 {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Shades of Purple",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue"
 }
```

Y debería de aparecerme algo parecido a esto:

```
{
   "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
   "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
   "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
   "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
   "files.exclude": {
         "**/.classpath": true,
         "**/.project": true,
         "**/.settings": true,
         "**/.factorypath": true
   },
   "java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-16.0.1.9-hotspot",
   "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
   "java.configuration.runtimes": [

   ],
   "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme"
}
```

Agradecería inmensamente que alguien pudiera ayudarme,

Un saludo :)

Comment: Ese archivo lo puedes editar manualmente y agregar la entrada "java.home"

Comment: Podrías elaborarlo un poco más?